# Designing ASP MVC routing - listing child objects of specific objects with pagination and filtering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have been looking at the feasibility of porting over an intranet web app from ASP DOTNET to ASP MVC. I have not yet decided whether or not this kind of framework would be suitable for the application.

One consideration is what the routing would look like...

The main use of the application is to CRUD 7 main types of objects, which, for illustration, include representations of customers, locations and persons. A customer can have multiple locations (< 10), which can each have many persons (maybe 1000s). Pages will either focus on the details or editing (often by multipage wizards -- another post though) of specific objects, or the listing out (with filtering) of sets of objects (eg persons) related to a particular object (eg a customer).

Just considering customers, beyond CRUD I will want to be able to list the various objects related to a specific customer (like locations and persons), page them, and also filter them by certain properties or keywords from a textbox. Currently, to view a customer's persons you would go to /customer?guid=1234#persons where there is a RadControls data grid containing all the persons (large request but bandwidth is not bottleneck).

So what would you recommend for routes?

Easy:
Customer/Edit/[GUID]

Harder:
Customer/List/[GUID]/Persons/[Page]?filter=xyz&paramX=YZ
or
Customer/List/Persons/customer=guid&...
or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what makes sense to you and your team.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have an issue with your urls changing then maybe you could look at a REST style url for the functionality your provide (even though you're not returning Xml or JSON).

Customer/Persons/GUID/xyz/yz/

Nonetheless the option you provided last is better since it is more intuitive then the previous one.

I should add that you can use ASP.NET routing in a ASP.NET Webforms application as well. So there is no need to re-write your app in ASP.NET MVC.

If you're used to using the WebForms controls then you're better off using WebForms.